# RoR: how to build a query containing only endorsements from people from the same company

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

For my statistics page I want to display the number of users and endorsements, and count and display only those that are in the same company as the currently logged in user.

My Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inbound_endorsements, class_name: "Endorsement",
                                 foreign_key: "endorsed_user_id",
                                 dependent: :destroy
  has_many :outbound_endorsements, class_name:  "Endorsement",
                                  foreign_key: "endorsing_user_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :endorsing_users, through: :inbound_endorsements, source: :endorsing_user
  has_many :endorsed_users, through: :outbound_endorsements, source: :endorsed_user
  #company
  belongs_to :company, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
```

And my Endorsements model:

```
class Endorsement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :endorsing_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :endorsed_user, class_name: "User"
  validates :endorsing_user_id, presence: true
  validates :endorsed_user_id, presence: true
  validates :comment, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140}
  scope :current, -> { where(created_at:  (Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now)) }
end
```

Gathering the data for the statistics page in a controller:

```
def statistics
    @users = User.where(activated: true, company_id: current_user.company)
    @endorsements = Endorsement.all #wish to modify this
    @data = @users.map { |user|
            amount = user.inbound_endorsements.joins(:endorsed_user).group(:name).count
            if !amount.empty?
              {name: user.name, data: amount}

            end
          }
  end
```

I thought of constructing something along those lines:

```
@endorsements = Endorsement.joins(User).where(endorsing_user.company == current_user.company)
```

To Select only those endorsements where the endorsing_users company_id is the same as the current_user one.

I will appreciate any help! If you need more information, please let me know.

Best regards,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from current_user's side,

Make a scope on `endorsement` model

```
# endorsement.rb
scope :endorsed_by_company, -> (company) { joins(:endorsing_user).where("users.company" => company) }
```

And finally, it would look something like this

```
@endorsements = Endorsement.endorsed_by_company(current_user.company)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, But i don' think this is what i want. I don't want to count endorsements for the current user that came from the same company. If i have a couple companies, i want to count all the endorsements the company has (the currently logged in users company). So when user from Company A logs in, he will see X endorsements, when a user from company B logs in, he will see his B company Y endorsements. And in total there will be X+Y endorsements in te whole database.

Comment: There is total of 2 endorsements in the DB, 1 from company A and 1 from company B's employees. The method you posted, shows 0 for currently logged in user, no matter which company i log into. And i wish to show that there are 1 endorsements respectivly for both employees

Comment: @Helban okay, I misunderstood, in that case, just call the scope on all `Endorsement`, that should do the trick. I made the changes

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you so much! Not the first time i see scopes being so powerful, yet i just don't understand how to use them correctly like you did, Is there any good source of explanation how to use the power of scopes to the max? I've tried documentation etc. But it wasnt really helpful in my case

Comment: no worries. i think [this tutorial](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/) explains scope pretty well